# Python: Removing all words that start with a Capital Letter and does not arise after punctuation

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to use regex to remove all words from a text that start with a capital Letter and satisfies these two conditions:

1) They are followed by only lower case letters or " 's" (possessive) or punctuation (.,?!).

2) They do not come after ".", "!" and "?"

I tried

```
import re

myString='The name of her company is Water Company WC 123 WaTerCompany! She was going to meet Daniel. Why? Because Daniel is her boy friend. Patricia? The daughter of Susana! Look, Daniel\'s car is white'
regex='([A-Z][a-z\']*)(\s[A-Z][a-z\']*)*'
txt = re.sub(regex, " ", myString)
```

I am getting

```
name of her company is    123    !   was going to meet  .  ?   is her boy friend.  ?   daughter of  !  ,   car is white
```

I want

```
name of her company is  WC 123 WaTerCompany! She was going to meet . Why? Because is her boy friend. Patricia? The daughter of ! Look, car is white
```

Comment: Why is `Patricia` removed in your expected output? It is a capitalised word right after a `.`.

Comment: You are right. Sorry! Edited!

Comment: And a small issue: the `,` after `Look` should also not be removed.

Comment: Well, there is a way to support any amount of whitespace before the word.

Comment: Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/sHTlrR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove *whole words*, you want to use `\b` boundary anchors, so that you don't match a partial word. To remove words that are preceded by punctuation, you can use a negative lookbehind, *provided* that there is always a fixed amount of whitespace between the punctuation and the first letter.

I'm going to assume that there is always one space between the punctuation and the next letter. You can always normalise your input first by replacing multiple spaces with one space.

That makes the regex to remove these words:

```
\b(?<![!?.]\s)[A-Z][a-z]*(?:'s)?\b
```

and a demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> myString='The name of her company is Water Company WC 123 WaTerCompany! She was going to meet Daniel. Why? Because Daniel is her boy friend. Patricia? The daughter of Susana! Look, Daniel\'s car is white'
>>> regex = r'\b(?<![!?.]\s)[A-Z][a-z]*(?:'s)?\b'
>>> re.sub(regex, " ", myString)
'  name of her company is     WC 123 WaTerCompany! She was going to meet  . Why? Because   is her boy friend. Patricia? The daughter of  ! Look,   car is white'
```

or try the pattern online, at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Q4bi4x/1).

Comment: The lookbehind should be placed after the word boundary for better performance.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: thanks, that indeed removes some 180 steps from the matching process.